# Can I get a function's signature using decltype?

Tags: c++

Currently, I have a function like this:

```
int get_something(int a1, int a2) {

}

// templated class which holds the address of the func and its type (return + params)
SomeClass<int(int, int)> object(&get_something);
          // ^get_something's return & params types
```

However, there's some functions that have a lot of params & long types, so sometimes I have to write stuff like:

```
HANDLE func(HANDLE, LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE, LPDWORD, LPVOID, ...)
```

Which results in:

```
SomeClass<HANDLE(HANDLE, LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE, LPDWORD, LPVOID, ...)> object(&func);
```

What I tried is:

```
SomeClass<decltype(func())> ...;
```

But it doesn't work.

Is there any way of getting the function's signature and passing it to the object without having to type all of that?

**Edit**
Here's my actual code.

EATEntry:

```
template<typename ret, typename... args> class EATEntry<ret(args...)> { ... }
```

Object declaration:

```
EATEntry<decltype(CreateThread)> CreateThread_f("CreateThread");
```

CreateThread's signature:

```
WINBASEAPI
_Ret_maybenull_
HANDLE
WINAPI
CreateThread(
    _In_opt_ LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
    _In_ SIZE_T dwStackSize,
    _In_ LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
    _In_opt_ __drv_aliasesMem LPVOID lpParameter,
    _In_ DWORD dwCreationFlags,
    _Out_opt_ LPDWORD lpThreadId
    );
```

**Edit2**

I've found out that my code actually works, **but** it works **only** with my own functions. If I try to use some Windows function (e.g. `CreateThread`), I get an "incomplete type" error.

Comment: I guess you need to read a little bit about decltype: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype

Comment: `decltype(func())` gives the type that `func` returns, since you're calling it in the expression. You could use simply `decltype(func)`.

Comment: @Cameron and nilo: Yeah, I've tried it, but it says "incomplete type not allowed" then. Not sure why...

Comment: I stopped reading at _"However, there's some functions that have a lot of params & long types"_. Simply don't do that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm creating references to Windows functions such as `CreateThread`. My functions are never that long... e.g. `SomeObject<HANDLE(_In_opt_ LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, _In_ SIZE_T dwStackSize, _In_ LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress, _In_opt_ __drv_aliasesMem LPVOID lpParameter, _In_ DWORD dwCreationFlags, _Out_opt_ LPDWORD lpThreadId)> CreateThread(...);`

Comment: _"I've tried it"_ No, you haven't, as [it works perfectly](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fa40ab904766712). Present your _testcase_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You're extremely helpful, and your right in 99.95% of cases. I've read a couple of your comments of the past hours: Is it possible that you're not your cheerful self right now? If that's the case, have an imaginary cold drink *hands over a drink through the interwebs*, and take a deep breath :) thanks for always being there for C++ questions!

Comment: @AcidShout: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I posted my actual code, I didn't put any example, and there's everything you need to compile it, even `CreateThread`'s signature

Comment: @AcidShout: Mate. Click on the link and read. Please. This generally goes better when you help us to help you.

Comment: Does it work if you type out the whole function signature for CreateThread? Your post isn't clear on that.

Answer (score 0):

You could have tried more than just one approach before asking.

Only a minor tweak is needed: don't call the function, but instead *name it*:

```
SomeClass<decltype(func)> c;
```

---

Here's an example showing that it works:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int x, char y, bool z)
{
    std::cout << x << y << z << '\n';
}

template <typename F>
void bar(F f)
{
    f(1, '2', true);
}

int main()
{
    bar<decltype(foo)>(foo);
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8dc0198d457c2c17))

Of course, in reality, you'd let the template argument be deduced here rather than giving it explicitly, but this shows that `decltype(foo)` is correct.

Comment: I edited my answer, adding my actual code; it doesn't work. The error I get is "incomplete type not allowed"

Comment: @AcidShout What compiler are you using? [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a654233ce5612569) is an example that also uses variadic templates, and works. It is exactly your test case.

Comment: @vsoftco I'm using MSVC 2013. For the sake of testing, I copy & pasted your code into a new project, and it compiled just fine... weird...

Comment: @AcidShout the "incomplete type not allowed" error smells like you're using some class as an incomplete type (not fully defined). You can only do this if you're using a reference or pointer to it. Simplify your example to the bare minimum and you'll find the issue. As mentioned in this answer, `decltype` works.

Comment: @vsoftco I posted the exact code I'm using in my project; it's not an example (check the edit). I looked carefully but still I can't see what's wrong. On a side note, if I declare and use a new, random function, it works! `void do_something(int a1){} EATEntry<void(int)> obj("obj");` works, but Windows' functions don't work (i.e. my functions work, Windows' don't)

Comment: Sorry, I meant `EATEntry<decltype(do_something)> obj("obj");` lol, typo. Can't edit since 5 minutes have passed.

Comment: What about `decltype(&func)`?

Comment: @celticminstrel why would that work? I don't want a type that is a pointer to such a function, but rather the function type itself. Anyway, I tried it, and no, it doesn't work

Comment: Suggested it because pointers to functions behave exactly like functions in most cases.

Comment: @AcidShout: Instead of repeating "it doesn't work" over and over again, why can't you present a _minimal testcase_ per the site rules as I've invited you to do several times? This is becoming extremely tedious.